# How does light look like when it is 180° out of phase?

Tags: waves, visible-light, interference, sun

When two lights are 180° out of phase, would it look like this?
In the photo below, the left side is flipped and it is a mirror image.
[image]

Comment: Please do not delete and repost a question that has been closed. You are supposed to edit the original question and wait to see if it gets reopened.

Comment: There are no "lights" there. There's just bits in a computer file that tell your monitor and my monitor how bright or dark to make certain pixels in the screen. Also, a light source such as the Sun doesn't have a phase. From a physicists perspective, the Sun is not a single light source. Instead, every atom in the Sun's photosphere is an independent light source, emitting photons with different wavelengths and different phases at random, with no correlation to what any of its neigbor atoms are emitting.

Answer (score 4):

When people talk about phases of a light field, they usually refer to the **electric field** $E$. To understand why this is of interest, consider  two light sources in 1D. Their (skalar) electric fields at the position $z_0$ are given by $E_1(z_0)=|E_1| e^{i\phi_1(z_0)}$ and $E_2(z_0)=|E_2| e^{i\phi_2(z_0)}$. The relative phase $\phi_2(z_0) - \phi_1(z_0)$ of these fields determines, whether they are constructively or destructively interfering. Since photographic plates and ccd chips do not measure the electric field, but measures the intensity, $I\propto |E_{total}|^2 = |E_1(z_0) + E_2(z_0)|^2$, the relative phase is important.

What you are doing is fundamentally different. You took the intensity of an image $I(x,y)$ for all negative $x$ values and just reused it for all positive $x$. Not only is it rather meaningless to ask  about a relative phase of two intensities in general, but you do not have two intensities at the same point in the image.

======

I'm not sure whether or not you know how two electric fields, which are 180deg out of phase look like. Here are two simulations. The light sources are located at $x=\pm 12$ and $y=0$. In the left image the electric field of the sources are out-of-phase by 180deg, and in the right image they are in-phase

[image]

In both I plot the intensity.